# Required Fields in PHP or Die

Tags: php, forms, insert, field, required

so i'm having trouble with the following: (let me know if you need all of the code).

```
$required = array('exam_id', 'subject', 'exam_date');

$error = false;
foreach($required as $field) {
if ( !empty($_POST['insert'])) {
$InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO Exam (exam_id, subject, exam_date) VALUES ('$_POST[uexam_id]','$_POST[usubject]','$_POST[uexam_date]')";
mysql_query($InsertQuery, $con);
$error = true;
}
} 
if ($error) {
die ("All fields are required!");

echo "<a href='examisud.php'> Back to Form </a>";
}
```

Essentially I want all fields to be required. And when one is left out, an error will pop up saying "All fields are required". 
The above code doesn't work as when all of the fields are filled in, the error pops up and doesn't add them to the database. However when a field is left missing, the error will pop up, but it will add the fields filled in to the database so essentially;
-The insert statement is no longer working.
-It works when 1 or more fields are left blank.
-I need all fields to be required and when 1 is left blank, an error will pop up and text will show to take you back to complete the form.
Thanks in advance for any help!

(Also, don't worry about SQL injections, this is a personal project on my own wamp server)

Comment: Sidenote: Your `echo "<a href='examisud.php'> Back to Form </a>";` will never show because of the `die()` Use `die ("All fields are required! <a href='examisud.php'> Back to Form </a>");` if you want to show the link. When it dies, there's no more life after that. Bodies don't move after being put 6 feet under; unless... ;-)

Comment: SQL injection-ready code, it is.

Comment: It's a personal project, it's never going online, no worries of SQL injection, thanks though!

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you are trying to do.  I think this is the check you are looking for in order to determine if one of those required fields is empty: foreach($required as $field) {
 if(empty($_POST['u'.$field]))
 { $error = true; }
}

Comment: Keep in mind though the empty function returns true if the input is 0 so... this won't work if you ever need to accept 0 for anything (exam id maybe?)

Comment: @AndrewNee I basically want to be able to insert values into the fields and if a field is left blank I want an error to pop up and say "Fill in missing field" with a link back to the php form.

Comment: A bit confused... if one of the required fields is left out, you want NOTHING to insert, correct?

Comment: I'm actually a bit confused at your approach too... do you want this code to work for any insert, or just this specific one with these 3 columns?  Because if you're just doing this specific one, I don't see the purpose in having the required array, etc.  You can just check if any of those 3 post variables is empty.

Comment: My approach is onorthodox yes, but i'm a newbiw at all of this and this is just my personal way so far of doing it by splicing code i've found around this site that works for what I want.
"if one of the required fields is left out, you want NOTHING to insert, correct?"
Yep, that's correct, I want an error to pop up and say that not all fields have been filled in essentially.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, you're going to want: [in_array](http://www.php.net/in_array)

Also your code is very unsafe, I would take precautions and also `mysql_` functions are now depreciated. You may want to look into [mysqli_](http://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo)

---

`in_array` will check if a value is found within the array.

```
$my_array = array("Your Value", "The Value", "Awesomeness");
if (in_array("Your Value", $my_array)) {
    //success, it was found in our array
} else { /*Not found, do something.*/ }
```

I hope this clarifies stuff, I'm still unsure what you're asking, but I think this is what you're asking.

Comment: It may have been more useful to just put this as a comment. But oh well

Comment: I edited my original question, this isn't going online, it's just for personal use on a project.
And i'm a newb so you're gonna have to dumb down this in_array stuff o.O

Comment: I added more details. Still unsure if this is what you were asking.

Comment: I'm not sure in_array will work, unless he/she cycles through the POST array and checks if the key of each of them is in the required array... but would have to strip off the "u" in front first.

Comment: No, that's not what i'm looking for unfortunately :/ Thanks your your input and advice anyway!

Comment: Something like this... foreach($_POST as $key) 
{ 
 if(in_array(substr($key, 1),$required)
 { //check if the variable is empty here, if so, set error to true }
}

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump($InsertQuery)` just after you declare it to see what's wrong

The single quotes don't pass the value, but interpret it literally. Remove them and the query will be operable.

Comment: Where would I put that exactly?

Comment: In between of `$InsertQuery = "INSERT...`and `mysql_query($InsertQuery, $con);`
You might aswell use `die(var_dump($InsertQuery));` to stop further execution and error

Comment: Ok I put it in, but I didn't change anything else, now when I insert into all the fields or if I miss one, I get: 
'string 'INSERT INTO Exam (exam_id, subject, exam_date) VALUES ('e333','Dynamic_Web_Development','2014-6-6')' (length=99)'

Was there other stuff I was supposed to change too? Sorry for wasting your time, I am quite new at this!

Comment: Did you remove the single quotes from query?

Comment: $InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO Exam (exam_id, subject, exam_date) VALUES ($_POST[uexam_id],$_POST[usubject],$_POST[uexam_date])";

Like that? Yeah, I still get the same thing :/

Comment: OK, now you are passing the variable values instead of names. Remove die(var_dump($InsertQuery)); and rewrite next two lines like this:
`$result = mysql_query($InsertQuery, $con); if (!$result) { $error = true; }`

Comment: Here's my code now: (comment in next comment)

_$required = array('exam_id', 'subject', 'exam_date');

$error = false;
foreach($required as $field) {
if ( !empty($_POST['insert'])) {
$InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO Exam (exam_id, subject, exam_date) VALUES ($_POST[uexam_id],$_POST[usubject],$_POST[uexam_date])";
$result = mysql_query($InsertQuery, $con); 
if (!$result) { $error = true; }
  }
} 
if ($error) {
  die ("All fields are required! <a href='examisud.php'> Back to Form </a>");
}_

Comment: Ok, that works for validating the insert, however, now when I fill in all of the fields, I still get "All fields need to be filled in", etc.
So essentially that works for them needing to be required but now it won't let me insert values into the table :/ Thanks for all your help btw!

Comment: You're welcome. Try to rewrite query like this `...VALUES ('".$_POST[uexam_id]."', "."'".$_POST[usubject]."', "."'".$_POST[uexam_date]."')"`

Comment: No, that puts me back to square one, I get an error when all fields are entered and when one is left blank, but the filled in data values still go into the database on refresh o.O :/

Comment: Ok, I'm running out of ideas. Try this query `"INSERT INTO Exam (exam_id, subject, exam_date) VALUES (\`$_POST[uexam_id]\`,\`$_POST[usubject]\`,\`$_POST[uexam_date]\`)"`

Comment: Nope, I get a parse error with the '`'. is it something I have to take out maybe?

Comment: what does the error say? will it work if you add \ in front of each `?

Comment: I changed !empty to isset and still the same.

Comment: I added \ in front of each ` and got:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\StudentExams\examisud.php on line 32

Comment: Woops, I was missing a semi-colon at the end of your last suggestion query. Doesn't do any good though, still the same stuff, not inserting anything :/

Comment: OK, last try: `"INSERT INTO \`Exam\` (\`exam_id\`, \`subject\`, \`exam_date\`) VALUES ('".$_POST[uexam_id]."', "."'".$_POST[usubject]."', "."'".$_POST[uexam_date]."')"`

Comment: Nope, that didn't work, While both game me errors such as:
Use of undefined constant uexam_id - assumed 'uexam_id' in C:\wamp\www\StudentExams\examisud.php on line 31

When I left a field out, it was added to the database, when I filled in all three, nothing was added :/
Thanks for your help, you've gone above and beyond, you don't have to try and help anymore i'll try and figure it out and post here if I get it!

Comment: You need quotes inside $_POST[] like $_POST['usubject']. You can use single quotes here. I wonder how I didn't spot it earlier...

Comment: So:

`"INSERT INTO `Exam` (`exam_id`, `subject`, `exam_date`) VALUES ('".$_POST['uexam_id']."', "."'".$_POST['usubject']."', "."'".$_POST['uexam_date']."')";`

?????

Comment: Not working either dude, don't know what to tell ya :/
How do I rep you anyway for your troubles?